# how to avoid code duplication in HTML and SASS

Tags: html, sass

I want to avoid the sass duplication here.

This is my HTML codes.Here I have repeated `map-report-toolbar-button-layout` several time and hard corded image. I what to get image path from the SASS file and need to avoid these duplications.

```
<div class="map-report-toolbar-background">
  <img src="assets/images/Background- s.png" />
</div>

<div class="zoom-in-button map-report-toolbar-button-layout"></div>

<div class="zoom-out-button map-report-toolbar-button-layout"></div>

<div class="center-button map-report-toolbar-button-layout"></div>

<div class="refresh-button map-report-toolbar-button-layout"></div>

<div class="zoom-to-extend-button map-report-toolbar-button-layout"></div>

<div class="publish map-report-toolbar-button-layout"></div>

<div class="reportoption-button map-report-toolbar-button-layout"></div>
```

### SASS file

```
.map-report-toolbar-background {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.map-report-toolbar-button-layout {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.zoom-in-button {
  background-image: url("/images/ZoomIn-s.png");
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.zoom-out-button {
  background-image: url("/images/ZoomOut-s.png");
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.center-button {
  background-image: url("/images/Center-s.png");
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.zoom-to-extend-button {
  background-image: url("/images/ZoomExtent-s.png");
  margin-top: 130px;
}

.publish {
  background-image: url("/images/Download-s.png");
  margin-top: 170px;
}

.refresh-button {
  background-image: url("/images/Reset-s.png");
  margin-top: 212px;
}

.reportoption-button {
  background-image: url("/assets/images/setting-s.png");
  margin-top: 253px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one  with different states "in / out / disabled / reload", i think the better way to update this it to use css variables

```
.my-button {
  // here your default button values
  --button-margin: 50px;
  --button-image: url('/images/ZoomIn-s.png');

  margin: var(--button-margin);
  background-image: var(--button-image);

  // here your variations
  &.-out {
    --button-margin: 30px;
    --button-image: url('/images/ZoomOut-s.png');
  }

  &.-bar {
    --button-margin: 70px;
    --button-image: url('/images/ZoomBar-s.png');
  }
}
```

You have the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but this is little bit unclear for me. can you please map your example with my actual codes? then I can get more idea about this.